# iOS8 transition - Different UINavigationBar/UITableView underlap/overlap behavior vs iOS7

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, ios8, uinavigationbar

under iOS7.1 my `UITableView` appears "correctly" (the way I want it) but under iOS8 the `UITableView` is underlapping the navigation bar. Why? (And how to fix?). I can force the behavior I am looking for in iOS8 by setting `navigationBar.translucent = NO`, but this is a hack and I lose the transparency.

**iOS7: Navigation bar does NOT overlap**

[image: iOS7]

**iOS8: Navigation bar overlaps**

[image: iOS8]